# Looking for a jQuery text counter that can do multiple text areas!

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I've looked around and haven't able to find a plugin that will do exactly what I need:

1. Be usable on multiple text areas per page.
2. Have a minimum and maximum limit
3. Display characters and warnings while the user types.

Ideally, it would be nice if the plugin/function prevented/enabled the form based on the character limit.

Where can I find something a plugin with such specs?

Should I write my own? I am a complete novice in jQuery and JavaScript, so the latter option is not desirable. But I can tinker and copy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to write such a thing...

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
    var maxsize = 1000;
    if( $(this).val().length > maxsize)
        $(element).val($(element).val().substring(0, maxsize));
});
```

You can also make it more generic... Just a basic example:

```
<textarea data-min="10" data-max="1000"></textarea>

$('textarea').keyup(function(){
    var maxsize = $(this).data('max');
    if( $(this).val().length > maxsize)
        $(element).val($(element).val().substring(0, maxsize));
});

$('textarea').blur(function(){
    var minsize = $(this).data('min');
    if( $(this).val().length < minsize)
        alert("Mininum size for this textarea is " + minsize);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write you own, based on the keypress event. Should be pretty simple:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('someelement');
var formSubmitButton = document.getElementById('someelementsParentform');

textarea.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    checklength(this, minvalue, maxvalue, formSubmitButton)
}, false);

function checkLength(thiselement, min, max, formSubmitButton){
if(thiselement.length < min || thiselement > max){
    formSubmitButton.disabled = true;
}else{
    formSubmitButton.disabled = false;
}
```

That's untested code, but i believe it should work

To use it on another textarea, just add an event listener to that text area and call the function.

Comment: keyup event would work as well

Comment: You could also just return true or false from `checkLength` and then do something in the event listener based on what `checkLength` returned.